# mouseover event on xul menubutton

Tags: css, firefox-addon, xul, onmouseover

I want to change the display of the button on the mouse over event of the menu button.
It shows the button border on the mouse over event of the menu-button and also the separation of the button and the drop down.

```
<toolbarbutton id="search" type="menu-button" label="SEARCH" width="83" height="25" oncommand="webSearch();event.stopPropagation();" onmouseover="">
   <menupopup>
      <menuitem label="Web" value="webs" oncommand="webSearch();event.stopPropagation();"/>
      <menuitem label="Images" value="images" oncommand="imageSearch();event.stopPropagation();"/>
   </menupopup>
</toolbarbutton>
```

Comment: give some code for better understanding

Comment: <toolbarbutton id="search" type="menu-button"  label="SEARCH" width="83" height="25" oncommand="webSearch();event.stopPropagation();" 
             onmouseover="">              
              <menupopup>
                <menuitem label="Web" value="webs" oncommand="webSearch();event.stopPropagation();"/>
                <menuitem label="Images" value="images" oncommand="imageSearch();event.stopPropagation();"/>
              </menupopup>
            </toolbarbutton>

Comment: sorry my cntrl is not working. Well the code is for creating the menu button. i want on mouseover event that the button shud be not display the borders. even if we are applying an image to it with css the borders are visible on mouse over

Comment: @gargi: please, show your complete CSS code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you want it to do? You can add some CSS to change it's style when you hover over it?

```
#search:hover {
   /* your styles here */
}
```